# How to configure Eclipse (Java) to recognize custom assertion when checking against potential null pointer

Tags: java, eclipse, assertion, design-by-contract

I have the following piece of Java code:

```
public void silence(final Object key) {
    final Chain chain = (Chain)getChain(key);
    checkPrecondition(chain != null);
    chain.silence();
  }
```

The checkPrecondition call raises a runtime exception if chain is null, but Eclipse doesn't seem to "get this": it says chain.silence() is a possible null pointer access (warning).
Question: How can I "tell" Eclipse that checkPrecondition() ensures that chain is not null, i.e. has the character of an assertion? I know that I can disable this warning, but I'd rather not do that, because in other situations, it might be justified.

Interestingly enough, when I remove the checkPrecondition() call, the warning disappears (which is precisely the case in which I'd expect to see it).

I use Eclipse 4.4.2 (32 bit) on Windows. Java VM is 1.3 (!). Update to newer versions of either is not currently an option.

Comment: Unrelated: since you worry about code quality ... consider if you really want to follow that ugly approach of putting "final" everywhere. Having chain being final adds *zero* value to this method. It is just line noise serving no real purpose.

Comment: In this case, usage of "final" has admittedly limited benefit but also no cost. So no loss altogether. In other contexts, usage of "final" communicates the intent of the programmer, and can cause coding errors to be detected at compilation time rather than by tedious testing. Our coding guideline explicitly calls for usage of "final", and so do most modern and serious coding guidelines that I have seen. Very high benefit!

Comment: And because of that, the Java language folks invested precious time in improving the compiler to detect **effectively** final variables - so that you don't have to write down final for local variables that dont get changed afterwards ;-) ... and as you got me curious: can you give some example links?

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell Eclipse, you have to produce a code in such a syntax and logic that the Java compiler will compile successfully and that the JVM will be able to execute.

It's normal that a runtime exception occurs. A variable value can only be checked at runtime, same for the null pointer (in fact it's the case in almost every language pretending to come from C and using something related to pointers and it was already the case before C).

You can solve this problem using two different approches, depending your style and the one used in your projet.

- First comes the defensing way --> you consider that the subprogram
  should be killed before such an error occurs (null pointers errors
  cost a lot in the software industry).

  ```
  public void silence(final Object key) {

      if (key == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should not be null.");
      }

      Object oChain = getChain(key);

      if (oChain == null || !(oChain instanceof Chain)) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key should be mapped to an object from the Chain class type.");
      }

      Chain chain = (Chain)oChain;
      if(checkPrecondition(chain)) {
           chain.silence();
      }
  }
  ```
- The second way is offensive : the calling code should handle this and the subprocess doesn't have to crash anything !

  ```
  public boolean silence(final Object key) {
      if (key == null) return false;
      Object oChain = getChain(key);
      if (oChain == null || !(oChain instanceof Chain)) return false;
      Chain chain = (Chain)oChain;
      if(!checkPrecondition(chain)) return false;
      chain.silence();
      return true;
  }
  ```

**Please note** that I suppose the *checkcondition* method is returning a boolean and that its single argument should be an object from the Chain class.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply, many thanks. However, I don't really see an answer to my problem. The problem is that with the checkPrecondition() call in place, Eclipse complains, even though there is no problem (null case handled). With the call not in place, there **is** a problem (null case **not** handled), but Eclipse does not complain. Increasing the code size so substantially a per the above is not an option in our case. On the other hand, your hint to check not only against null but also against "instanceof" is well taken.

Comment: What I mean with "tell Eclipse" is this: PC lint, for example, allows me to state that a certain custom expression acts like an assertion, and shall be seen as synonym to "assert" during static code analysis. This makes a lot of sense and this is what I am looking for in Eclipse.

Comment: With my version: no complains. Well I understand you are confused but your code doesn't seem to compile at all (especially the *checkPrecondition* call cause you pass a boolean where another type is awaited, at least I hope so). Normally, you just not try to modify the Eclipse Linter which is probably one of the greatest help you will ever have (the guys behind are very good programmers and you can trust them). If you do that, you don't need Eclipse anymore. Update a code is far more simpler than modifying Eclipse itself: imagine modifying the Linter each update or new arrivals on the project.